# Install docker WS 2016 no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.14393 in the manifest list entries

Tags: linux, windows, docker, server, devops

**Hello,
I'm trying to install docker on windows server 2016: Here is the process I made :**

INSTALL NUGET

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet _MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force
```

INSTALL DOCKER PROVIDER

```
Install-Module -Name DockerMsftProvider  -Repository PSGallery -Force

Install-WindowsFeature Hyper-V -IncludeManagmentTools
```

INSTALL DOCKER

```
Install-Package  -Name docker -ProviderName DockerMsftProvider -Force
```

```
Restart-Computer -Force
```

DOCKER DAEMON

```
Get-Service -Name docker
```

START DOCKER SERVICE

```
Start-Service -Name docker


[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.securityProtocolType]::Tls12

docker search microsoft
```

CREATE DAEMON.JSON in programData/docker/config

```
{
 "registry-mirrors": [],
 "insecure-registries": [],
 "debug": false,
 "experimental": true
}
```

```
Restart-Service docker 

docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/nanoserver
```

Here is my docker info:

```
 Client:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  app: Docker Application (Docker Inc., v0.8.0)
  cluster: Manage Mirantis Container Cloud clusters (Mirantis Inc., v1.9.0)
  registry: Manage Docker registries (Docker Inc., 0.1.0)

Server:
 Containers: 3
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 3
 Images: 1
 Server Version: 20.10.7
 Storage Driver: windowsfilter
  Windows: 
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: ics internal l2bridge l2tunnel nat null overlay private transparent
  Log: awslogs etwlogs fluentd gcplogs gelf json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Default Isolation: process
 Kernel Version: 10.0 14393 
 Operating System: Windows Server 2016 Datacenter Version 1607 (OS Build 14393.4770)
 OSType: windows
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 2
 Total Memory: 7.999GiB
 Name: OSCAR3
 ID: AEF3:RVUB:G2XN:QIOV:PFA6:MZF5:DW76:SA5W:MPLJ:7D4Z:GEVT:EKUQ
 Docker Root Dir: C:\ProgramData\docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: true
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Here is my docker version :

```
 Client: Mirantis Container Runtime
 Version:           20.10.7
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.13.15
 Git commit:        40ef3b6
 Built:             08/19/2021 18:54:26
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Mirantis Container Runtime
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.7
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.24)
  Go version:       go1.13.15
  Git commit:       e1bf5b9c13
  Built:            08/19/2021 18:53:20
  OS/Arch:          windows/amd64
  Experimental:     true
```

I tried `docker pull php` and I got this error:

```
docker : no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.14393 in the manifest list entries
```

`docker pull php-amd64` and I got this error:

```
docker : Error response from daemon: pull access denied for php-amd64, repository does not exist or may 
require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

I'm trying to make run node images or debian images, but nothing is working. I tried to switch to a linux or windows container by this command:

```
& $Env:ProgramFiles\Docker\Docker\DockerCli.exe -SwitchDaemon
```

But it's not working.